# How to link to the libabc.a instead of libabc.so?

Tags: build, build-process, automake, libtool

In the book [Autotools: A Practioner's Guide to GNU Autoconf, Automake, and Libtool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593272065), chapter 6 (building libraries with libtool), an [example](http://nostarch.com/download/autotools-book-files.tar.gz) of linking library is given.

In the example, a library `libjupiter.so` is linked to another library `libjupcommon.a`. The first attempt fails because `libjupiter.so` needs PIC, but `libjupcommon.a` is not. The author adds `libjupcommon_a_CFLAGS = -fPIC` to fix it. It gets much better, but the warning of '*Linking the shared library libjupiter.la against the static library ../common/libjupcommon.a is not portable!*' appears.

Therefore the author modifies the Makefile.am's again, using libtool to build `libjupcommon.la`. The `libjupiter` links to the `libjupcommon.la`.
Like this:

> noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libjupcommon.la
>
> libjupcommon_la_SOURCES = jupcommon.h print.c

and

> ...
>
> libjupiter_la_LIBADD = ../common/libjupcommon.la

This time everything's OK.

---

Now, my problem:

I have a library needs another library, just like `libjupiter` needs `libjupcommon`. The difference is my `libjupcommon` is from another project and installed into the system. It is not a `noinst_LTLIBRARIES`. Both `.so` and `.a` version exist. When I try to link the `libjupcommon.la` like the example shows, the `.so` is chosen, but I don't want a dynamic linking relationship. I want to link to the `.a`, like the example in the book.

Linking to `.a` explicitly (by using _LIBADD=the .a file) gives a usable library, but the warning of '... not portable' is given.

What's the proper way to achieve linking to the `.a` in this case?

PS: Download the example from the [book's official site](http://www.nostarch.com/autotools.htm). In `autotools/book/jupiter-libtool-ch6/common`, modify the Makefile.am's `noinst_LTLIBRARIES` to `lib_LTLIBRARIES` should be a close mimic to my problem.

Comment: What can of library do you want to build?  A shared library or a static library?  It make no sense to link with the installed `.a` library if you are building a shared library, hence the libtoool warning.  If you are building a static library, you should explicitly state so (see ldav1s' answer).

Comment: I want to build a shared library. It makes no sense even if the installed `.a` is PIC? Why is it so?

Comment: But in that case the `.a` was not generated by Libtool.  As far as I know, the `.a` files installed by Libtool are not PIC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple things you could try.  You could try running `configure` with the `--disable-shared` option to turn off compilation of shared libs (and add the static lib to `libfoo_LIBADD` again).  You could try adding `-static` to `libfoo_LDFLAGS` to get libtool to build it statically (again with the static lib added to `libfoo_LIBADD`).

EDIT:  Since both static and shared libs are needed the above won't work.

Try adding:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([abc],[some_function_in_libabc])
```

to configure.ac.

Comment: You mean to compile the static one only? I think it will work. But I need both static and dynamic `libjupcommon`; and make `libjupiter.so` links the static one.

Comment: noinst_LTLIBRARIES are convenience libraries, intended to be relinked with some executable or other library during the build.

Comment: After reading the code of libtool, I am convinced that building a static only library is what I should do. Like libfoo.so, libfoo.a libfoo_static.a. Thanks ldav1s.

Answer (score 2):

You can force static linking to *one* library (while keeping all other links shared) using this construct:

```
-Wl,-Bstatic -Wl,-whole-archive -Xlinker -l$1 -Wl,-no-whole-archive -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

Replace $1 above with your library name.

Explanation: Most of the above monstrosity is to get around the fact that libtool will re-arrange the command line arguments, ever so helpfully. Using -Xlinker will force libtool to ignore the -l$1 and not re-arrange it. The -Wl,-Bstatic tells the linker to link all following libraries as static. -Wl,-Bdynamic switches back to dynamic linking for further libraries.